# Using Ipset and Iptables for MAC address filtering

Tags: iptables, mac-address, ipset

I use MAC address filtering on my Linux router. Here is what I have done:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth5 -m mac --mac-source 00:07:e9:84:2b:99 -j RETURN #User: Someuser
iptables -A INPUT -i eth5 -j DROP
```

But the Iptables rule list is huge with more than 400 entries. Recently I read about the advantages of using Ipset with Iptables [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/384132/iptables-limit-rate-of-a-specific-incoming-ip/384155#384155). But nowhere I have found any howtos about doing same thing with MAC filtering. So how can I use Ipset for MAC filtering in order to reduce the size of Iptables rule table.

Answer (score 2):

Basically something like this, but you have to associate an IP with a MAC, pure MAC sets do not seem to exist:

```
# ipset --create test macipmap --network 10.0.0.0/16
# ipset --add test 10.0.0.1,00:11:22:33:44:55
# iptables -A INPUT -i eth5 -m set --match-set test src -j ACCEPT
```

Here, you see the content of the map and the reference-counter indicating an iptables rule referencing this set:

```
# ipset -L test
Name: test
Type: macipmap
References: 1
Header: from: 10.0.0.0 to: 10.0.255.255
Members:
10.0.0.1,00:11:22:33:44:55
```

There are some things to consider:

- That type of set is technically restricted to 64k consecutive addresses (not sure whether they have to be "subnet-aligned"), found it [here](http://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html)
- Your kernel has to support ipset, most common standard distribution kernels unfortunately do not
- You could set static ARP alternatively
- MAC addresses can be spoofed easily

Comment: Found out today, that ipset has been added to the vanilla kernel since 2.6.39!