# limit upload/download speed per IP in Cpanel

Tags: iptables, ftp

I have some abusers on FTP which suck all my 100MBs on the server. How I could stop that from Cpanel or iptables or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar situation.  My situation was resolved in this ServerFault post:

[IPTABLES - Limit rate of a specific incoming IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/384132/iptables-limit-rate-of-a-specific-incoming-ip)

Answer (score 1):

While I strongly advise you not to use ftp but sftp, you can :

- Ban offending ip with iptable
- Use an alternate port so that web bots will take longer to brute force your ftp server.
- Limit the number or ftp sessions depending on the ftp server you use.